# How i config spring boot + elasticsearch and postgresql

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, elasticsearch

i'm a newbie i want to config project spring boot with elasticsearch and postgresql.
i want to write the api if FE transmisson in the param isES = true, we call the function connect Elasticsearch else we call the function connect with postgresql.
please help me

thanks

```
`@Autowired
private SinhvienesRepo sinhvienesrepo;
@Autowired
private Search essearch;
@Autowired
private SinhvienRepo sinhvienrepo;
@GetMapping("/sinhvienes")
Iterable<Sinhvienes> Sinhvienes() {
    return sinhvienesrepo.findAll();
}

@GetMapping("/sinhviens")
List<Sinhvien> Sinhvien() {
    return sinhvienrepo.findAll();`
```

Comment: Adding your code to display what you have tried always gives reader better idea.

Comment: yes i alredy add code . i using to repository one for postgre one for es. 
it work well but i want to combine it on one api . and when i request parameter issearch es = true it will get funtion es repository and else it will get function of postgres